# Does parents saying "the marriage is over" end the marriage?

Tags: nikah, talaq

Hi I'm a 18 year old living in Canada. I went to Pakistan at the age of 16 and got married to a 26 year old because my parents wanted me to. I came back to Canada in less than a week. My husband abused me over Internet, threatened me and cheated on me within 6 months of our Nikah. He never really cared about me except for my visa.

I want divorce I am going for khula. If my parents end the marriage is it over? My ex husband ( as I consider him now) doesn't Care about me at all. I was told if parents tell their child that the marriage is over then it is? Is that true?

Comment: did you sign a marriage contract? Does he fulfil your rights as a wife?

Comment: Did he cheat or is this women a seconded wife? The marriage is between you him and Allah not you parents. Only your husband or a Islamic board of scholars can issue you a divorce.

Answer (score 2):

No. The marriage is still in effect. The marriage will be terminated after khula. It happened in Pakistan. So, the process of termination will be according to Pakistan's law.

You have been misinformed regarding divorce in Islam. Parents saying “the marriage is over” does not end the marriage. If you need further advice regarding what you should do, you could ask questions regarding your problems on [Quora.com/Islam](https://www.quora.com/topic/Islam) (there are many wonderful brothers and sisters there who would love to help you).